# jQuery and radio button groups

Tags: jquery, radio-button

In jQuery, I'd like to select all groups of radio buttons where there are no buttons checked.

Or, is there a way in which I can select all radio button groups and iterate through the groups?

I'm dynamically adding N radio button groups to a page and will not know, before hand, what the names of the radio button groups will be.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To find all radio groups:

```
var radio_groups = {}
$(":radio").each(function(){
    radio_groups[this.name] = true;
})
```

to find which radio group has checked radio boxes and which hasn't:

```
for(group in radio_groups){
    if_checked = !!$(":radio[name='"+group+"']:checked").length
    alert(group+(if_checked?' has checked radios':' does not have checked radios'))
}
```

Comment: what does !! stand for and why?

Comment: [Duble NOT, it converts boolean value two times in a row so `!!true = true`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript/1406618#1406618)

Comment: I know this is old, but this has helped me out so much! I just wanted a simple way to ensure that each of my radio button groups was selected, and here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Support for multiple groups and pre-checked.

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var $t = $(event.target);
    if ($t.hasClass('checked')) $t.removeAttr('checked');
    else $('input[type="radio"][name="' + $t.prop('name') + '"]').not($t).removeClass('checked');
    $t.toggleClass('checked');
}).filter(':checked').addClass('checked');​
```

```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/abrkn/PGW2Z/

Answer (score 0):

To select all radio by group name and obtain only the list of different names:

```
    function selectRadioByGroupName() {
        return $.unique($('input:radio').map(function(index, element) {
            return this.name;
        }));
    }
```

An example snippet:

```js
function selectRadioByGroupName() {
  return $.unique($('input:radio').map(function(index, element) {
    return this.name;
  }));
}



$(function () {
  selectRadioByGroupName().each(function(index, element) {
    $('body').append($('<p>First Group name is: ' + element + '</p>'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
    <p>
        Q1:
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
    <br />
    <p>
        Q2:
    </p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="male"> Single<br>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="female"> Married<br>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="other"> Other
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="submit_id" value="Submit" onclick="submitAnswers()">
</form>
```

After getting the different group names it's possible to cycle on them.