# JavaScript !! operators

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929)

I've seen operator `!` used like `!!`. For example

```
var filter = !!(document.body.filters);
```

If I'm not wrong it's equivalent `var filters = typeof document.body.filters != 'undefined'`?

Is it a good practice to use `!!`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-operator-mean-in-javascript

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: duplicates of duplicate report!

Comment: Not actually a duplicate of any of those. Those ask what `!!` does. This questions asks whether it's good practice to use `!!`.

Comment: Now I see - my question looks like a duplicate. But I've tryed to find about '!!' here in SO before asking, but without success.

Comment: Tadas is right, if you search for "!!" on SO you get the search options page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common way to convert any return type to boolean (usually to avoid compilation warnings).
And second: no, checking if type is "undefined" is mandatory anyway and "!!" can not cover it.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking if type is "undefined" is mandatory anyway and "!!" can not cover it."?

Comment: "!!" will only allow you to check if operand is zero of any king, but only "typeof()" can tell you if the operand is defined. "!!" for undefined operand will throw a error.

Comment: OK, I see what you were getting at now. It's not always true that `!` (and hence `!!`) will throw an error for an undefined operand: for example, `!!window.bananas` will not throw an error while `!!bananas` will. But in general for testing if an object or property is undefined, `typeof` (an operator, not a function, so no parentheses required) is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you. All `!!` does is "cast" its argument to a Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

! negates the result of whatever is on the right. So !! negates the negated value thus ending with whatever was originally on the right.

edit: the above is true if you have boolean values, results may vary for other types ...

edit2 to elaborate some more: !! is a "type cast" operator of sorts. if you have a boolean value on the right then nothing will happen. If you have something other then a boolean value on the right, then the first ! will convert whatever is on the right to the boolean "version" of that value, and the second ! will negate that value.
Kinda like saying: return the true value of a non boolean value.
Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: not true. this is so only for booleans, which are not the question's subject.

Comment: It's true regardless of whatever the original type was.

Comment: That depends on whether whatever was on the right was a boolean value.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The result of a `!` or `!!` operation will always be a Boolean, regardless of its original argument.

Comment: in fact, no matter how many negations you tack together, the result is always boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`var filter = !!(document.body.filters);`

is **NOT** equivalent to

`var filters = typeof document.body.filters != 'undefined'`

`!!` merely checks if the operand is "truthy", i.e. whether it evaluates to true when used in a boolean expression. It has no relation to `typeof`. In general with host objects (such as `document.body.filters`) you are best off using `typeof` checks. The following article is good reading on this subject: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting

Answer (score 0):

And what if it is a string with value "undefined"?

I think !!(expression) is neat.

Comment: then the typeof expression will return "string"