# When to use the double not (!!) operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean

I understand [what the double not operator does in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript). I'm curious about it's use though and whether or not a recent assertion that I made is correct.

I said that `if (!!someVar)` is never meaningful nor is `(!!someVar && ...` because both the `if` and the `&&` will cause someVar to be evaluated as a boolean so the !! is superfluous.

In fact, the only time that I could think of that it would be legitimate to use the double not operator is if you wanted to do a strict comparison to another boolean value (so maybe in return value that expects true or false explicitly).

Is this correct? I started to doubt myself when I noticed jQuery 1.3.2 used both `if (!!someVar)` and `return !!someVar && ...`

Does the double not have any actual effect in these situations?

My personal opinion is that it just leads to confusion. If I see an if statement, I know it's evaluating it as a boolean.

Comment: Note that (as Justin points out in his answer to the question you reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript/1407785#1407785), there is no double-not operator. `!!`  merely applies the not operator twice.

Comment: This 'operator' is the very definition of idiomatic... Unless you know what it is, you're likely to be confused or simply misread this as a single 'not'. I'm going to start using it just to confuse my co-workers :D If anybody's interested, I saw this in the 'wild' in jQuery.grep

Comment: related: [What is the difference between if(!!condition) and if(condition)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19818574/1048572)

Comment: see also [Why use `if (!!err)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27257803/1048572) and [Why use `!!` to coerce a variable to boolean for use in a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648179/1048572)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the context of [`if` statements](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.5) I'm with you, it is completely safe because internally, the `ToBoolean` operation will be executed on the condition expression (*see Step 3 on the spec*).

But if you want to, lets say, return a boolean value from a function, you should ensure that the result will be actually boolean, for example:

```
function isFoo () {
  return 0 && true;
}

console.log(isFoo()); // will show zero
typeof isFoo() == "number";
```

In conclusion, the [Boolean Logical Operators](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.11) **can return an operand**, and not a `Boolean` result necessarily:

The Logical AND operator (`&&`), will return the value of the *second operand* if the first is *truly*:

```
true && "foo"; // "foo"
```

And it will return the value of the *first operand* if it is by itself *falsy*:

```
NaN && "anything"; // NaN
0 && "anything"; // 0
```

On the other hand, the Logical OR operator (`||`) will return the value of the *second operand*, if the first one is *falsy*:

```
false || "bar"; // "bar"
```

And it will return the value of the *first operand* if it is by itself non-falsy:

```
"foo" || "anything"; // "foo"
```

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the *falsy* values are: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, zero-length string, and of course `false`.

Anything else (that is not *falsy*, a `Boolean` object or a `Boolean` value), evaluated in [*boolean context*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2), will return `true`.

Comment: Another way of saying this: the logical AND operator returns the first "falsy" operand encountered, while the logical OR operator returns the first "truthy" operand. Also, for the sake of completeness, -0 is also considered "falsy".

Comment: If you are in a situation where you need to `!!expr` something, consider writing it `Boolean(expr)` instead for the sake of readability, as it is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Here's a use case I encounter regularly:  short-circuit rendering in JSX.  You can end up rendering a '0' if you try to render a the elements of a zero-length array.  I made a codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/lucask42/full/GGbqdv/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, !!var is used when you want 0||1 return value.

One is simple comparison of bool values, when you want "a == b" be equivalent of "a xor not b" except a=5 and b=7 would both be true but not be equal.

Another is when you want to coerce a set of conditions into bits of a variable:

```
 var BIT_NONEMPTY=1;
 var BIT_HASERRORS=2;
 var BIT_HASCHILDREN=4;
 var BIT_HASCONTENT=8;

 result_bitfields = 
    (!!countLines())*BIT_NOTEMPTY +
    (!!errorCode())*BIT_HASERRORS +
    (!!firstChild())*BIT_HASCHILDREN +
    (!!getContent())*BIT_HASCONTENT;
```

Not very useful in Javascript which lives pretty far from bit values, but may be useful at times.

Comment: No: !! converts to false or true, not 0 or 1.  (In your bitfield example, true is then coerced to 1 and false to 0 by the * operator).