# Is the !! operator even necessary in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I can understand cases when you will want to convert an object value to a boolean and save it in a variable. However, I came across the following code in a jQuery template and was wondering if the !! (double exclamation operators) is even necessary.

```
{{if !!sectionId}}
    // do something...
{{/if}}
```

I am assuming that it is not since Javascript will automatically evaluate the expression following the if as boolean. Therefore, you could just write:

```
{{if sectionId}}
    // do something...
{{/if}}
```

Am I right in my assumption?

Comment: Possibe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: This is the most close duplicate IMO: [How to use the double not (!!) operator in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174297/how-to-use-the-double-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `!!` operator in JavaScript. There's just `!`.  What you're seeing is a doubled application of that single operator.

A single application of `!` will return a boolean by evaluating the "truthiness" of its argument, giving the boolean inverse of that. The second `!` therefore gives the boolean inverse of *that* value, which is thus the boolean "truthiness" of the original value.

Personally I wouldn't use it in a simple `if` statement as in your example, but it's handy for APIs that might explicitly check for a boolean-typed parameter:

```
someAPI( !! someExpression );
```

Comment: I realize that. I had looked at this post initially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript. I am still curious if using this implementation is even necessary for this situation.

Comment: It's necessary when the code, for whatever reason, *really* needs a boolean value.  Some APIs explicitly check for a boolean and not a truthy value in function argument lists etc.

Comment: type security can be an issue, if you want to make sure a function returns a boolean, it can be important to cast: `return !!(this.foo || this.bar)` would be unnecessary in other languages, but `||` and `&&` don't actually return booleans, they just returns the first `truthy` and `falsey` values they come across (respectively).

Comment: To add to Pointy's answer and comment, JavaScript has many truthy values, aside from 'true'.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224

Comment: If you're casting to a boolean, it's more clear to use the boolean cast function Boolean(x);