# What is the difference between if(!!condition) and if(condition)

Tags: javascript

I often see code that uses `!!condition` as opposed to just the regular condition. I.e.:

```
if(!!value){
    doSomething();
}
```

versus:

```
if(value){
    doSomething();
}
```

What is the funcational difference, if there is one? Is one superior to the other? What, if any, are the conditions for picking to use one versus the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain this 'double negative' trick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick)

Comment: See also [How to use the double not (!!) operator in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2174297/1048572)

Comment: @JonathanNaguin: No it's not.

Comment: See also [Why use `!!` to coerce a variable to boolean for use in a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648179/1048572)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically nothing. The double bang `!!` type converts `value` to a boolean - something the if statement does when it evaluates `value` anyway.

In the code you have posted, the `!!` is useless and serves no purpose.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a more explicit way to test the "truthiness" of a value.

The following will "cast" `value` to a boolean.

```
!!(value)
```

For example, a non-empty string

```
!!"a" // true
```

Another example with an empty string

```
!!"" // false
```

---

However, if you simply test a value directly using

```
if (value) // ...
```

then the following values are `false` in JavaScript

- `0`
- `-0`
- `null`
- `""` (empty string)
- `false`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

**everything else** is `true`

Comment: When used in if condition it may not be meaningful but when used as a return value, it can be used to send the boolean value. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The !! ensures the resulting type is a boolean (true or false).

javascript:alert("foo") --> foo

javascript:alert(!"foo") --> false

javascript:alert(!!"foo") --> true

javascript:alert(!!null) --> false

They do this to make sure $('row') isn't null.

It's shorter to type than $('row') != null ? true : false.