# Not not (!!) inside if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements

Note: it's actually a duplicate of [What is the difference between if(!!condition) and if(condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19818574/938236)

While I understand [what the **!!** means (double not)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/938236), for this same reason it doesn't make sense to me its use [in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Worker_feature_detection):

```
if (!!window.Worker) {
...
}
```

Isn't this exactly the same as this for this situation?

```
if (window.Worker) {
...
}
```

The casting to boolean makes no sense for me since the `if` will only be executed if the `window.Worker` exists. To say that it's `True` or `Object` for an `if()` conditional (I think) is the same.

**So, why is the `!!` used here? Or, why is the `window.Worker` casted to boolean inside an `if()`?**

Comment: Please refer to the original one (the linked as a dup is actually a dup): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818574/what-is-the-difference-between-ifcondition-and-ifcondition

Comment: People who come from typed languages are uncomfortable with truthiness. Therefore you see this sort of code as a sort of "readable code" style documentation that it's checking for the boolean value rather than the object itself. People who're used to javascript programming will typically not do this.

Comment: @slebetman that's why it didn't make sense for me then! Your comment should be the answer, since it not only explains that it's the same, but one possible cause (:

Comment: It should be noted that Mozilla, while to us is a software that executes javascript, to the Mozilla devs it is C/C++ code for a web browser. So the documentation are sometimes written by C++ developers rather than javascript developers. Javascript developers wouldn't dream of creating a function called `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is exactly the same. Nothing to add.

It might have been used to emphasize that the `window.Worker` property - expected to be a function - is cast to a boolean for detecting its presence, instead of looking like a forgotten `()` call. Regardless, [it is now gone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers$compare?locale=en-US&to=803901&from=799087).

Comment: Nice touch! I guess Bergus there is also you