# double bang performance scenario

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Just wondering if there is any benefit (performance or otherwise) to using double bang in this scenario:

```
const isUser = users && !!users.find((u) => u.id === '123')

if(isUser) {
 console.log('is user')
}
```

Does it make sense to use double bang here? Wondering if converting it from a user object to boolean has any benefits when checking it with `if(isUser)`

Comment: See [Why use double exclamation marks in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230490/why-use-double-exclamation-marks-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: In that scenario, they are asking if it is worth using !! on a variable that is already a boolean, bit different

Comment: No, read the second half of the question.

Comment: My mistake, thanks. Care to add that to the answer?

Comment: Why are you reinventing `some` or `every`?

Comment: Performance can be benchmarked. Did you?