# Is there an interest to use double boolean negation?

Tags: javascript, boolean

As a beginner in Javascript, I have a question which may seem a bit weird.
I am using an external lib I found on the web in which I found the code below :

```
if('useHoles' in c){
   this.config.useHoles = !!c.useHoles;
}
```

Is there an interest to use the double exclamation mark or is it just some clumsy code ?

Couldn't find any answer yet so I guess I can just remove them but I wanted to be 100% sure.

Comment: `!!` turns `falsey` and `truthy` into real boolean values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use the double not (!!) operator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174297/when-to-use-the-double-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the  double `!` you force an object to return something that is "*boolean-able*", even if `null` or something else, that can be evaluated as bool `true` or `false`.