# What does this expression mean "!!"

Tags: javascript

Why would somebody use an expression like

```
if(!!window.JSON) alert('exists');
```

instead of just

```
if(window.JSON) alert('exists');
```

?

Is there another usage for the "!!" thing ?

Comment: Multiple negatives are though to understand, that's why. If you keep using if(!!(!!)!!!(!)!!obj) in your code, only you can maintain it (if your lucky) - I'm not no undummy!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript/1407769#1407769 ; and you're right, in this case it's redundant, as `if()` already converts to boolean

Answer (score 15):

`!!` will simply cause a boolean conversion, it is not necessary at all to use this construct with the `if` statement, also in your first snippet, converting *an object* to boolean makes no sense, it will be *always true*.

The only values that can coerce to `false` are `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, and empty string and of course `false` anything else will coerce to `true`.

When it makes sense to use `!!` is when you want to make sure to get a boolean result, for example when using the Logical `&&` and `||` operators.

Those operators can return *the value* of an operand, and not a boolean result, for example:

```
true && "foo"; // "foo"
"foo" || "bar" ; // "foo"
```

Imagine you have a function that test two values, and you expect a boolean result:

```
function isFoo () {
  return 0 && true;
}

isFoo(); // returns 0, here it makes sense to use !!
```

**Edit:** Looking at your edit, `if (!!window.JSON)` is just redundant as I said before, because the [`if` statement](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.5) by itself will make the boolean conversion [internally](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2) when the condition expression is evaluated.

Comment: Looks like you meant to write something like `function isFoo(obj){ return obj && true; } isFoo(0);` in the last example :) or `return !!obj && true;`

Comment: `false && "foo"` evaluates to *false*.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yep, was a typo s/false/true, @Znarkus, yeah, just something for expository purposes ;) Thanks guys...

Answer (score 2):

They're probably trying to cast the object to a boolean. By applying a boolean operator (`!`) to the object, it becomes a bool, but they don't actually want the negation, so they apply a second one to cancel the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
// !! = boolean typecasting in javascript

var one = 1
var two = 2;

if (one==true) app.alert("one==true");
if (!!one==true) app.alert("!!one==true");

if (two==true) app.alert("two==true"); // won't produce any output
if (!!two==true) app.alert("!!two==true");
```

Comment: that's why you should use `===` and cast explicitly: the `==` type conversion rules are something of a WTF

Answer (score 1):

! is a logical negation, !! is the logical negation applied twice, ie the logical identity

I would assume the code you are reading is just being harmlessly (albeit confusingly) redundant.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't the question involve an implicit type-cast from object to boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Its a boolean conversion, ensuring a conversion to boolean the first time then negating back to the original value.

However it is used incorrectly here and would only really be relevant if you assign it to another variable - for performance reasons

```
var isJSON = (!!window.JSON);

if (isJSON) doX;
if (isJSON) doY;
if (isJSON) doZ;
```