# Prototype Library use of !! operator

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does this expression mean “!!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059546/what-does-this-expression-mean)
>   [What does the !! operator (double exclamation point) mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript)

Here is a snippet from Prototype Javascript Library :

```
  Browser: (function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var isOpera = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.opera) == '[object Opera]';
    return {
      IE:             !!window.attachEvent && !isOpera,
      Opera:          isOpera,
      WebKit:         ua.indexOf('AppleWebKit/') > -1,
      Gecko:          ua.indexOf('Gecko') > -1 && ua.indexOf('KHTML') === -1,
      MobileSafari:   /Apple.*Mobile/.test(ua)
    }
  })(),
```

This is all good and i understand the objective of creating a browser object. One thing that caught my eye and I haven't been able to figure out is the use of double not operator **!!** in the IE property.

If you read through the code you will find it at many other places. I dont understand whats the difference between `!!window.attachEvent` and using just `window.attachEvent`.

Is it just a convention or is there more to it that's not obvious?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059546/what-does-this-expression-mean

Comment: @Daniel Thank you; I was positive this had come up before but searching for `!!` is rather difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont understand whats the difference between `!!window.attachEvent`  and using just `window.attachEvent`.

The key of understanding this, is to know that the [Boolean Logical Operators](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.11) can return an operand, and not a Boolean result necessarily:

The Logical AND operator (`&&`), will return the value of the second operand if the first is truly:

```
true && "foo"; // "foo"
```

And it will return the value of the first operand if it is by itself falsy:

```
undefined && "anything"; // undefined
NaN && "anything";       // NaN
0 && "anything";         // 0
```

So, in the snippet `!!window.attachEvent && !isOpera`, we already know that `isOpera` is a boolean value, `!!` will just make sure that `Browser.IE` is a boolean result also.

An example: let's say we are in Firefox, `window.attachEvent` is `undefined` and `!isOpera` is `true`, if you don't use the double negation, `Browser.IE` would be `undefined` instead `false`.

Comment: +1 for excellent explanation with example. too good!

Answer (score 4):

It's a fairly common trick used to coerce a value to a boolean type, instead of using `(bool)`. `!window.attachEvent` would negate the truth value of `window.attachEvent`, giving you a boolean; `!!window.attachEvent` negates that, giving you the original truth value but as a boolean instead of the type of `window.attachEvent`

Comment: imo this is a much better answer then the accepted one (which talks more about && then !!).

Comment: @Matt, the real question was "Why use `!!window.attachEvent && !isOpera` instead of just `window.attachEvent && !isOpera`", the OP was not really asking what `!!` does (fact that I think the OP already knows). To understand why you need `!!` in that condition, you need to know how the `&&` operator behaves, this can cause confusion because in other languages the logical operators *always* yield a boolean value. That's why I talk about `&&` ;)

Comment: @CMS I think he was just asking what the point of double-negating something was, he said "If you read through the code you will find it at many other places. I dont understand whats the difference between `!!window.attachEvent` and using just `window.attachEvent`"; that his example used `&&` was just a coincidence I think. I found your answer educational though