# What is the difference if("test") and if(!!"test")

Tags: javascript

What is the difference `if("test")` and `if(!!"test")`, only judged the false or true;

Comment: I think I already saw a question like this, but I can't remember the topic

Comment: subject of your question is different to the body

Comment: @tm1rbrt: I fixed it, first editor edited it wrongly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript

Comment: I believe OP knows what `!!x` does, but the question is whether the two statements are equivalent in behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

The question has a [double negation](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2006/09/29/A-nice-and-compact-way-to-coerce-to-Boolean-in-JavaScript.aspx) expressson, that converts the type to boolean.

e.g.

```
var x = "test";

x === true; // evaluates to false

var x = !!"test";

x === true; //evalutes to true
```

Answer (score 6):

!! will convert a "truthy" value in true, and a "falsy" value on false.

"Falsy" values are the following:

- `false`
- `0` (zero)
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

If a variable `x` has any of these, then `!!x` will return `false`. Otherwise, `!!x` will return `true`.

On the practical side, there's no difference between doing `if(x)` and doing `if(!!x)`, at least not in javascript: both will enter/exit the if in the same cases.

EDIT: See http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/01/javascript-truthy-falsy/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

!! does type conversion to a boolean, where you are just dropping it in to an if, it is AFAIK, pointless.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference. As others point out,

```
!!"test"
```

converts to string to a boolean.

Think of it like this:

```
!(!("test"))
```

First, `"test"` is evaluated as a string. Then `!"test"` is evaluated. As `!` is the negation operator, it converts your string to a boolean. In many scripting languages, non-empty strings are evaluated as true, so `!` changes it to a false. Then `!(!"test")` is evaluated, changing false to true.

But `!!` is generally not necessary in the if condition as like I mention it already does the conversion for you before checking the boolean value. That is, both of these lines:

```
if ("test")
if (!!"test")
```

are functionally equivalent.

Comment: thanks  for you answer,  if(!! "var") widely used ,in Ext lib;
I think if("var") is equal to if(!! "var");