# Javascript - Weird if syntax

Tags: javascript

I am looking through some code that someone else have written and I noticed this strange javascript if syntax.. Basicly, it looks like this:

```
// This is understandable (but I dont know if it have relevance)
var re = new RegExp("^" + someVar + "_", "i");

// !!~ ??? What is this black magic?
if (!!~varA.search(re)) { ... }
```

This is one of those things that is hard to google.. Any Javascript gurues that can explain this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double exclamation points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284664/double-exclamation-points)

Comment: And also check this http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/

Comment: As for what it is... it's a pointless syntax that saves 0 characters when typing and lowers legibility. `varA.search(re)>-1` is it's 'brother'

Comment: I don't believe that this is a duplicate of other double-exclamation questions.  `!!~` is quite different from `!!`.  I'll admit, `!!~` is new to me.  It is cryptic and I think it warrants its own question.  I'd always prefer a much more expressive approach: `if(varA.search(re) >= 0)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unary operators like that just need to be interpreted from right to left. `~` is the bitwise "not" operator, and `!` is the boolean inverse.  Thus, those three:

- convert the return value to an integer
- invert the bits of the integer
- inspect the number for "truthiness" (zero or non-zero, `false` or `true`)
- invert the boolean value
- invert it again

The `~` here is the trickiest. The "search" routine (I surmise) returns `-1` when it doesn't find anything. The `~` operator turns `-1` to `0`, so the `~` allows one to interpret the "search" return value as `true` (non-zero) if the target is found, and `false` (zero) if not.

The subsequent application of `!` — twice — forces the result to be a true boolean value. It's applied twice so that the `true`/`false` sense is maintained. *edit* Note that the forced conversion to boolean is not at all necessary in this particular code; the normal semantics of the `if` statement would work fine with just the result of the `~` operator.

Comment: For reference, the `!!` is entirely unnecessary here.  You'd only need it if you were storing the result for later and wanted to be sure it was a boolean.  For immediate use in an `if`, it's overkill.

Comment: @cHao yes, in *this* example it's not necessary.

Comment: @cHao In fact you could go further and say that the `~` is overkill, as you can just add `+1` so the "no match" return value is falsy and the "match in first position" becomes truthy.

Comment: @Kolink:  You could.  But then again, `"~x".length < "x+1".length`.  :)

Comment: But I've never once used `~` for any legitimate purpose, and I'm sure most other programmers don't use it either. Okay if you're going for minimalist, but if you're encouraging readability... Heh.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `.search` returns the position at which it finds the result, or `-1` if it doesn't match. *Normal* people would just write:

```
if( varA.search(re) > -1)
```

But personally I'd just use:

```
if( varA.match(re))
```

Comment: Your second example would return `true` for `-1`, giving a false positive

Comment: @Bojangles: I must be missing something.  I'm not seeing the opportunity for a false positive here.  Note that the second example uses `.match` rather than `.search`.

Comment: If `varA.search()` returns `-1`, the `if()` will satisfy, however _no match was found_, therefore a false positive

Comment: @Bojangles Like cHao said, the second example uses MATCH, not SEARCH.

Comment: Well crap, that's embarrassing... sorry `:(`

Comment: (Scratch comment about inverted logic.  `~` confuses me for some reason.)

Answer (score 0):

In laymans terms

```
 ~
```

is doing -(N+1)
and

```
!!
```

The first bang casts from the number to a Boolean, and the second undoes the logical not that was performed by the first bang.

Have a look at this website.
it has a few explanations

http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/