# Form Data is not captured correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the below to capture the value "1" on checkbox selection and value "0" on unselection of a checkbox. The Problem I am facing is if I select the checkbox, the value "1" is capturing but if I didn't select the checkbox the value="0" is not captured on form data.

```
JS:
    <script>
    function setvalue() {
    if (document.getElementById('binary').checked = true) {
       document.getElementById('binary').value='1';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('binary').value='0';
    }
    </script>


HTML:
    <input name="Maximize" id="binary" type="checkbox" value=" ">
```

Comment: Look at the formatting colors.  Do you see something wrong?  Hint: you're missing the closing }

Comment: Change `= true` to `=== true`. `=` alone is an assignment operator, so the `value` is **always** being set to `"1"` and will never enter the `else` part

Comment: Good lord, please don't assign stringified numbers. `1` or `0` would be just fine

Comment: @SterlingArcher :  Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Element values are strings by default, but it's just bad practice to wrap an integer in quotes. It's like `if (x == "true")` where true is now a string instead of a boolean value. Also, cache your elements, so that you don't have to call `document.getElementById("binary")` every single time.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks. Can you please correct the above code for me?

Comment: I'm going to leave this one for you. You have plenty of comments to study up from. You got this!

Comment: I have tried the codes from below comments. none works

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked checkboxes will not be submitted.

Insert a hidden input before the checkbox:

```
<input name="Maximize" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="Maximize" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

However, it's redundant. When you parse the form-data on serverside simply assume a value of `0` when the variable is not set

Comment: I have tried this. It is capturing only the "0"s . When I select the checkbox the value "1" is not captured

Comment: captured by what? when you send the form and the checkbox has been checked, 1 will be submitted, otherwise 0

Comment: No matter I have checked or not, It is always capturing "0"s. Can you please correct my code above and show me how?

Comment: Correct, a script wouldn't help here when the control(form-field) is not successful(and a checkbox is only successful when it's checked). See: [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). My suggestion uses the hidden input(0) as default and when the checkbox(1) is checked it will overwrite the hidden input. No need for a script.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if (document.getElementById('binary').checked = true) {
```

should be

```
if (document.getElementById('binary').checked == true) {
```

or

```
if (!!document.getElementById('binary').checked) {
```

no?

Comment: Interesting cast to boolean there. Not many people use it like that

Comment: You can read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284664/double-exclamation-points#9284677) for more details :-)