# What's !! meaning when used in the of statement?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, youtube-javascript-api, javascript-automation

Such as if(!!you) , I thought we can  get rid of the !! , and it's the same. Cause JavaScript will change it to Boolean automatically?

Comment: duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284664/double-exclamation-points

Answer (score 0):

`!!` cast the variable to a Boolean. Similar to how you do `+foo` to cast it to a number.