# jQuery and radio button validation of groups

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-group

I'm hoping someone can help out with this. I modified code from [jQuery and radio button groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165627/jquery-and-radio-button-groups) but cannot get it to work. Here is my HTML:

https://gist.github.com/1319498

Here is the jquery:

https://gist.github.com/1319503

I fail the if statement in !!$(":radio[name="+group+"]:checked").length) and never set valid to true whether I chose a radio button or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the selector modifier with single-quotes:

```
!!$(":radio[name='"+group+"']:checked").length)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! Spent the last 2 days on this. Someone give mblase some votes (My rep is not high enough yet).